# Azure Audit Logs provide wrong information

Tags: azure, azureportal

If I see in my audit logs of my virtual machine I can clearly see the operation create or update virtual machine extension.
[image]

But when I want to filter on that operation name to see all the create or update vm extension, The result is zero.

[image]

This is also the case when i select start vm in the filter while I can see that inside my time range (that's in the filter) there is clearly an operation with the name start virtual machine. But the Filter is not showing me this result.

Any idea what I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

It looks like you were having multiple "Create or Update Virtual Machine Extension" operation names and you would have selected the one which returns null.

Please provide the operation name as "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write" and check if that resolves your issue.

As per this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-logs-overview#query-the-activity-log-in-the-azure-portal article, to get the precise output when using filters you would have to provide the "Operation localized value" (i.e., for example something like "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write", "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action", etc.) but not the "operation value" i.e., "Create or Update Virtual Machine Extension" or "Start Virtual Machine", etc.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!